# posts not appearing in the users stream

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

are the days gone where you could post to a users wall from php/curl and it appears on their wall and in the users feed?

been testing around with the new privacy- it appears on my wall but not in the friends stream.

heres my array am posting-

```
$attachment =  array(
               'access_token' => $token,
                'message' => $data['message'],
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'description' => $data['description'],
                'picture'=> $data['picture'],
                'icon' => $data['icon'],
                'href' => $data['href'],
                'link' =>$url,
                'caption' => $data['caption'],
                'privacy' => json_encode(array('value'=>'EVERYONE'))
      );
```

Some of the values are deprecated, I know but I built this when graph API first came out allowing to post.

whats the best way to get a friend attention now?

Answer (score 0):

What i use to post content to the stream of a user is slightly different:

```
$this->facebookapi->api(
    "/".$this->facebookuserid."/feed", 
    'post', 
    array(
        'message'=> 'I answered to this week\'s question and participated to contest.',
        'picture' => '', 
        'link'=> 'http://www.urltomysite.com/',
        'description'=>'Participation to the 2011 Facebook Contest',
        'name'=> '2011 Facebook Contest',
)
);
```

Tell me if it works. BTW, i'm using the facebook PHP SDK, that's what the $facebookapi object is...

Comment: i assume its the same its just i am using curl and your using the sdk?

Comment: I dunno, i'm just posting a possible solution, it does look similar, but it is different in the fact that i use the API and it abstracts some operations for me. Maybe try the API, it might work better and fix your problem, you never know...